# Como detectar o click do botão(html) no TChromium CEF4Delphi?

Tags: html, delphi

Eu tenho o componente TChromium CEF4Delphi carregando uma pagina web, e nessa pagina web tenho um botão.
É possível detectar o click deste botão na pagina web (html) e abrir por exemplo um form do delphi?

Se não for possível, existe um componente de navegador com essa opção?

Comment: Essa pagina é algo gerado pelo seu programa ou é algo aleatório? Você só vai conseguir detectar o clique em um botão de uma pagina que você controla, se você controlar a pagina chamada é só fazer a detecção do clique no botão (button.click) no front e chamar a API do delphi no back.

Comment: É uma página a parte, um simples Index.html local, o que seria controlar a página?

Comment: se é uma pagina local, quer dizer que você tem acesso ao código dela (isso que eu quis dizer com controlar a pagina), logo pode implementar uma chamada em JS ou php de uma API (procedure ou function) do delphi. Acredito que possa resolver seu problema estudando um pouquinho sobre: "como detectar um clique e chamar uma função" em JS, "chamada http de uma API" em JS e como "fazer um backend em delphi".

Comment: Entendi obrigado

Comment: Eu vou responder com um exemplo pra facilitar sua vida amigo. Um minuto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> É possível detectar o click deste botão na pagina web (html) e abrir por exemplo um form do delphi?

Sim, como citei nos comentários isso pode ser feito através de uma interação do front-end chamando uma API (através de uma requisição http) do back-end da sua aplicação web (e em questão de performance é recomendado fazer desse jeito), porém como você não postou nenhum código e para evitar uma implementação demorada para você eu vou usar as requisições e recursos do `Delphi` e do `TChromium`nesse exemplo:

---

Supondo que sua página html seja parecida com essa:

```
<html>
  <body>
     /...
     <button id="botao" type="button">Botão</button>
     /...
  </body>
</html>
```

Você deve identificar o elemento que deseja acompanhar com a propriedade `id`.
Como você pode notar, o botão possui a propriedade `id` com o valor "botao", ela será usada para  identificar esse botão. 
 
Agora faremos um `Listener` para o evento do do click do botão, farei isso através do evento que detecta quando a página carregou, o `OnLoadEnd`.
Então quando a pagina for carregada, o evento `OnLoadEnd` será disparado, eu varrerei o `DOM` da página em busca do elemento com o `id botao` e anexarei o `Listener` para o click do botão.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, cefvcl, ceflib;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Chromium1: TChromium;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Chromium1LoadEnd(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
      const frame: ICefFrame; httpStatusCode: Integer; out Result: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chromium1.Load('C:\File.html'); //carregando a página
end;

procedure TForm1.Chromium1LoadEnd(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const frame: ICefFrame; httpStatusCode: Integer; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(frame) then //Se acabou o carregamento da pagina executamos isso
    frame.VisitDomProc(OnExploreDOM); //chamada de evento OnExploreDOM para acharmos nosso botão
end;

procedure OnExploreDOM(const ADocument: ICefDomDocument);
var
  DOMNode: ICefDomNode;
begin
  // aqui tentaremos achar o elemento que você identificou com o id
  DOMNode := ADocument.GetElementById('botao');
  // e se acharmos o evento que queremos será anexado
  if Assigned(DOMNode) then
    DOMNode.AddEventListenerProc('click', True, BotaoClickEvent);
end;

procedure BotaoClickEvent(const AEvent: ICefDomEvent);
begin
  Form2.FormOpen; //aqui você indica o form que quer abrir e  
                  //como deseja abrir (Show, ShowModal, Open, etc.)
end;

end.
```

---

OBS: É válido lembrar que você pode utilizar essas pequenas mudanças no seu HTML para acompanhar qualquer elemento da página e é claro, você pode usar quantos `Listeners` quiser para acompanhar as interações com diversos elementos da página de uma vez só.